# The type or namespace name 'Document' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ocr, modi

I was created windows application in which MODI.dll & axmodi.dll were used for Image to Text (OCR processing) (Window-application- c#). It Worked fine without throwing an ERROR.

Now like to implement on ASP.net (C#) as the same. But it throw error even added needed Reference. ***"The type or namespace name 'Document' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*** This is the error i am getting.

Pls kindly help

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Is `Document` defined inside the library you are already referencing?

Comment: I was used same .dll for both windows & web appication. For webapplication only it shows that error. Not for windows application @JenishRabadiya . Moreover i an using .dll , so i canot check that